# How to assign types of (typeof) all elements in the object to a variable in JavaScript | Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a javascript object that looks like

I am trying to assign types of all the elements in the object to a variable where I am facing the issue,

whereas I am able to assign it when I mention the constants separately instead of using it them in an object in the second code snippet

```js
const a = Object.freeze({
REMOVE_ITEM:'REMOVE_ITEM'
ADD_ITEM:'ADD_ITEM'
});

//How to assign the types of all elements in the above object
const b = typeof ? // All Properties in the above object ((Facing Problem Here));

//I Can do it if 

const REMOVE_ITEM ='REMOVE_ITEM';

const ADD_ITEM = 'ADD_ITEM';

const b = typeof REMOVE_ITEM | typeof ADD_ITEM;
```

Comment: JavaScript does not know any types at all - this does confuse me a bit. So what are you really trying to achieve? You want `b` to be assigned the **value** of `REMOVE_ITEM`?

Comment: and your code is just plain JS - please tell us if you are talking about `typescript` types

Comment: Hi @messerbill, yes I am trying to achieve it using typescript and regarding the REMOVE_ITEM or ADD_ITEM I just wanted to assign the type of REMOVE_ITEM to b so that I can use it as type, please let me know if you require any other details

Comment: you did not write any typescript code at all. Assigning a type in ts looks like so: `const myVariable: MyType = .....`

Comment: Hi @messerbill , yes as you mentioned above we mention the type of variable with " : " type but I was trying to export a type in order to use it as a type for another variable.  eg:  const a = 'HELLO';  export typeof a; const b:a = .......

Comment: does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing JavaScript's `typeof` operator with TypeScript's - both do not accomplish the same thing.

In JS, `typeof something` will evaluate to a simple runtime string (such as `'number'`, `'string'`, `'object'`...) which your app can then use for comparison purposes. This is not what you want here.

In TS, `typeof` helps you extract the *implied TS type* out of a JS variable, as a meaningful structure - a true *TypeScript type*. This is helpful when you want to define complex TS types out of existing JS code.

```
const a = Object.freeze({
  REMOVE_ITEM: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
  ADD_ITEM: 'ADD_ITEM'
});

// ^ to TypeScript, this is similar to this type:
// Readonly<{ REMOVE_ITEM: string; ADD_ITEM: string; }>
```

To extract its implied type:

```
type AObject = typeof a;
// Readonly<{ REMOVE_ITEM: string; ADD_ITEM: string; }>
```

To have type definitions matching the keys in that object, use `keyof` when defining your TS type matching any key:

```
type AKey = keyof AObject;
// "REMOVE_ITEM" | "ADD_ITEM"

// or in a strictly similar way:

type AKey = keyof typeof a;
// "REMOVE_ITEM" | "ADD_ITEM"
```

Now, back to runtime code. Once you have extracted the `AKey` type matching the *keys of `a`*, you can enforce type consistency for some JS values and arguments where needed:

```
function createActionObject(actionType: AKey) {
  return { type: actionType };
}

const action1 = createActionObject('REMOVE_ITEM');
// compiles and works as expected

const action2 = createActionObject('SOME_BAD_KEYNAME');
// TypeScript Error ->
// Type '"SOME_BAD_KEYNAME"' is not assignable to type '"REMOVE_ITEM" | "ADD_ITEM"'
```

---

*Finally*, you cannot "assign" TS types to a JS variable, you can merely describe what a JS variable needs to look like so TypeScript validates it before eventually transpiling to JS. If you tried to get an array that lists all keys in `a`, you need to use traditional JS methods:

```
const b = Object.keys(a);
// to JavaScript: will be ['REMOVE_ITEM', 'ADD_ITEM']
// to TypeScript: string[]

// or, to get stronger typings for `b` rather than just `string[]`:

const b = Object.keys(a) as (keyof typeof a)[];
// to JavaScript: will be ['REMOVE_ITEM', 'ADD_ITEM']
// to TypeScript: ('REMOVE_ITEM' | 'ADD_ITEM')[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScripts `as const` notation ([found here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)).

```js
const a = Object.freeze({
  REMOVE_ITEM: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
  ADD_ITEM: 'ADD_ITEM'
} as const);

// assign typeof 
const b: typeof a = {} as any; // you can ignore `{} as any` - only here for example

b; // type is { REMOVE_ITEM: 'REMOVE_ITEM', ADD_ITEM: 'ADD_ITEM' }
b.REMOVE_ITEM; // = 'REMOVE_ITEM'
b.ADD_ITEM; // = 'ADD_ITEM'

// destructure
const { REMOVE_ITEM, ADD_ITEM } = a;

REMOVE_ITEM; // = 'REMOVE_ITEM'
ADD_ITEM; // = 'ADD_ITEM'
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5zzkjj) so you can see the types in action.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you are trying to `export` a `type` to make use of it in another file. This is quite easy:

File with your type definition (myType.ts / myType.d.ts):

```
export type MyType = {
  foo: boolean
  bar: 'foo' | 'bar' 
}
```

File where you want to use that type:

```
import { MyType } from './myType' // should be in the same folder, otherwise correct the path

const myVar: MyType = false // error
const myVar: MyType = { foo: false, bar: 'foo' } //working
```

You can **not** define any types during the runtime since types will be removed while transpiling. But you can define an `enum` and use it to define your types:

```
enum MyEnum {
  FOO_BAR = 'foo_bar',
  LORD_OF = 'the_rings'
}
type MyOhterType = {
  fooBar: MyEnum
}

const myOtherVar: MyOtherType = {
  fooBar: MyEnum.FOO_BAR
}
```

Comment: Hi yes you were right but I was trying to assign multiple types to the "bar" which has to be taken from the Object keys from const a = Object.freeze({
REMOVE_ITEM:'REMOVE_ITEM'
ADD_ITEM:'ADD_ITEM'
});

Comment: @RajeshAlonea so you ask to create types during the runtime? This is not possible at all because all types are removed while transpiling to javascript.